# How to get last 4 characters of a string?

Tags: string, swift

I need to seperate the last 4 letters of a string. How can I seperate it? The length of string is changing.

Example:

```swift
var a = "StackOverFlow"
var last4 = a.lastFour // That's what I want to do
print(last4) // prints Flow
```

Comment: substring function..

Comment: @EricAya and other closers: This is not a duplicate of the linked question. In method call chains like  `[1,2,3].map({"Int(\($0))"}).joined(separator: ", ").last(x)`, `substringWithRange` and friends are useless.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43277938/539599) for a solution that works in method chains, i.e. without an external reference to the string itself. (Commenting here because this is the top Google result.)

Comment: **these days it's just `.suffix(4)`**

Answer (score 327, accepted):

**Swift 2:**

A solution is `substringFromIndex`

```
let a = "StackOverFlow"
let last4 = a.substringFromIndex(a.endIndex.advancedBy(-4))
```

or `suffix` on `characters`

```
let last4 = String(a.characters.suffix(4))
```

---

**Swift 3:**

In Swift 3 the syntax for the first solution has been changed to

```
let last4 = a.substring(from:a.index(a.endIndex, offsetBy: -4))
```

---

**Swift 4+:**

In Swift 4 it becomes more convenient:

```
let last4 = a.suffix(4)
```

The type of the result is a new type `Substring` which behaves as a `String` in many cases. However if the substring is supposed to leave the scope where it's created in you have to create a new `String` instance.

```
let last4 = String(a.suffix(4))
```

Comment: you da ma, all over the Swift strings! Can't find a string question without you on it

Comment: be aware that substring will crash if the string is less than 4 characters long

Comment: Unfortunately, this is useless in a chain like `[1,2,3].map({"Int(\($0))"}).joined(separator: ", ").last(x)` -- we don't have a handle on the string in such situations!

Comment: @Raphael `String([1,2,3].map({"Int(\($0))"}).joined(separator: ", ").characters.suffix(4))` does not work?

Comment: @vadian Let's pretend we are in the middle of a chain. ;)

Comment: @Raphael That's beyond the scope of this *last 4 characters* question.

Comment: Well, the question broad enough; I don't think it should have closed as duplicate. Of course, any answer may be as narrow as it wished; I just wanted to leave this comment since this is the top Google hit for me.

Comment: Thanks very much for this answer Vadian ! Your solution is so simple ! When we see the Apple documentation on it, we want to cry ...

Answer (score 17):

```
String substr = a.substring(a.length() - 4)
```

syntax is wrong. no type before vars in Swift.

```
let a = "1234567890"
let last4 = String(a.characters.suffix(4))
print(last4)
```

works on Swift 3.0

Comment: a.substring(a.length() - 4) particular syntax results in build fail. Solution : String(a.characters.suffix(4))