# Remove Last Two Characters in a String

Tags: ios, swift, string, swift3

Is there a quick way to remove the last two characters in a String in Swift?  I see there is a simple way to remove the last character as clearly noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24122288/remove-last-character-from-string-swift-language).  Do you know how to remove the last two characters?  Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32849789/how-to-get-last-4-characters-of-a-string

Answer (score 166, accepted):

update: **Xcode 9 • Swift 4 or later**

String now conforms to RangeReplaceableCollection so you can use collection method dropLast straight in the String and therefore an extension it is not necessary anymore. The only difference is that it returns a Substring. If you need a String you need to initialize a new one from it:

```
let string = "0123456789"
let substring1 = string.dropLast(2)         // "01234567"
let substring2 = substring1.dropLast()      // "0123456"
let result = String(substring2.dropLast())  // "012345"
```

---

We can also extend `LosslessStringConvertible` to add trailing syntax which I think improves readability:

```
extension LosslessStringConvertible {
    var string: String { .init(self) }
}
```

---

**Usage:**

```
let result = substring.dropLast().string
```

Comment: I just love swift.

Comment: Note that `String.dropLast()` returns a `Substring` so you may need to convert it to a String depending on how you're using it.

Comment: @Uncommon if you read the whole answer you would see that it is already stated in the post

Answer (score 61):

```
var name: String = "Dolphin"
let endIndex = name.index(name.endIndex, offsetBy: -2)
let truncated = name.substring(to: endIndex)
print(name)      // "Dolphin"
print(truncated) // "Dolph"
```

Comment: You just copy pasted from the link given by OP

Comment: The original link removes the last character, not the last two

Comment: In contrast to the `dropLast(..)` method [shown in @LeoDabus answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40028338/4573247), the method in this answer will yield a runtime exception for strings that are less than two characters (empty of only one character). Also, whereas the `dropLast` method is Swift native, `.substring` is bridged via Foundation from `NSString` (not entirely Swift native).

Comment: wouldn't better question be, how to select the first N characters, otherwise you need to test you'd have enough to stay non-nil

Answer (score 27):

swift 4:

```
let str = "Hello, playground"
let newSTR1 = str.dropLast(3)
print(newSTR1) 

output: "Hello, playgro"

//---------------//

let str = "Hello, playground"
let newSTR2 = str.dropFirst(2)
print(newSTR2)

output: "llo, playground"
```

Answer (score 2):

Better to use [removeLast()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/2894285-removelast)

```
var myString = "Hello world"
myString.removeLast(2)

output : "Hello wor"
```

Comment: This will fail if the string is shorter than 2. Per the docs: "Attempting to remove more elements than exist in the collection triggers a runtime error."

Answer (score 1):

Use `removeSubrange(Range<String.Index>)` just like:

```
var str = "Hello, playground"
str.removeSubrange(Range(uncheckedBounds: (lower: str.index(str.endIndex, offsetBy: -2), upper: str.endIndex)))
```

This will crash if the string is less than 2 characters long. Is that a requirement for you?