# How to get a substring in swift 4?

Tags: swift, string, swift4

I know we can use subscript to cut a part of the string in Swift 4, .

```
let s = "aString"
let subS = s[..<s.endIndex]
```

But the problem is, how to cut the `s` to a subString like `aStr`.
I mean, What I want to do is something like `s[..<(s.endIndex-3)]`.
But it's not right.
So, how to do it in Swift 4.

Comment: Whats wrong in it?

Comment: For `s[..<(s.endIndex-3)]`, the error is `Binary operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'String.Index' and 'Int'`

Comment: Use can learn from [here](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/updating-strings-for-swift-4/)

Comment: In this particular case you can simply call `let subS = String(s.dropLast(3))`

Comment: with `dropLast` you won't be able to extract internal range such as: `Stri`

Comment: @AndreaMugnaini OP is using PartialRangeUpTo operator

Comment: @JsW https://stackoverflow.com/a/38215613/2303865

Comment: and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40028035/remove-last-two-characters-in-a-string-swift-3-0/40028338#40028338

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`String.Index` is not an integer, and you cannot simply subtract
`s.endIndex - 3`, as "Collections move their index", see
 [A New Model for Collections and Indices](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0065-collections-move-indices.md) on Swift evolution.

Care must be taken not to move the index not beyond the valid bounds.
Example:

```
let s = "aString"

if let upperBound = s.index(s.endIndex, offsetBy: -3, limitedBy: s.startIndex) {
    let subS = String(s[..<upperBound])
} else {
    print("too short")
}
```

Alternatively,

```
let upperBound = s.index(s.endIndex, offsetBy: -3, limitedBy: s.startIndex) ?? s.startIndex
let subS = String(s[..<upperBound])
```

which would print an empty string if `s` has less then 3 characters.

If you want the initial portion of a string then you can simply do

```
let subS = String(s.dropLast(3))
```

or as a mutating method:

```
var s = "aString"
s.removeLast(min(s.count, 3))
print(s) // "aStr"
```

Answer (score 2):

As you said error is `Binary operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'String.Index' and 'Int'`

You have to find the `Swift.Index` first.

```
let s = "aString"
let index = s.index(s.endIndex, offsetBy: -3)
let subS = s[..<index]
print(String(subS))
```

Comment: This would crash if the original string has less than 3 characters. Better to use dropLast as proposed by Martin

Answer (score 2):

All I wanted was a simple Substring, from the start, of x characters. Here's a function.

```
func SimpleSubstring(string : String, length : Int) -> String {
    var returnString = string

    if (string.count > length) {
        returnString = String(string[...string.index(string.startIndex, offsetBy: length - 1)])
    }

    return returnString
}
```

usage

```
let myTruncatedString : String = SimpleSubstring(string: myBigString, length: 10)
```