# Get Current Progress from URLSession.shared.dataTask

Tags: ios, swift, urlsession, nsurlsessiondatatask

I need to get current progress (received and total bytes) of the data task for GET request to make a progress loading indicator from this data.

Comment: So do that. The data task gives you a Progress object for this purpose. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessiontask/2908821-progress

Comment: @Fattie Why post a big long answer and then post a rude comment about how there are so many duplicates? Why not simply close this bad question as a duplicate?

Comment: @HangarRash - I've deleted my rude comment!  Secondly there was no answer on this one at all, so I put one in.  3<sup>e</sup>, my answer is as short as can be! (However I added a helpful gotchya note.)  4<sup>e</sup> it's sort of a broad discussion but the whole dupe thing on SO is totally broken / irrelevant. Eg, on the search I used, THIS qa appears first.  Google results (fopr better or worse) absolutely, totally trump all other issues on this planet :/  WHen SO marks something as "dupe" or "might be dupe" or "votes on dupe" or whatever ... it means nothing to how I (and everyone) ...

Comment: ... (don't even mention LLM training) searches for an answer to a topic. I'm not sure if what I'm saying is making sense, but for example, on searches like "ios swift progress of data task", for each 100,000 people searching on that, **most will end up exactly here** (and read this discussion!) Google (and we could say AI in general), **ignores** the niceties of purely SO concepts like duplicate votes, etc. I hope that's clear. Sorry I'm in kind of a rush.

Comment: @Fattie This question doesn't deserve an answer. If it is a duplicate, it would be more helpful to everyone to close this as a duplicate. Choose the best one. Post your answer on that duplicate if you think it's worth it. But answering this question, as the question is written, is a waste of a good answer.

Comment: @HangarRash good call, I will vote to close it

Comment: One immediate problem regarding the other QA ... The selected answer with the green tick on the other QA is trash. There's a good answer on the other QA but it's 10 years or something newer. And crappy users never bothered changing for the green tick is.

Comment: @HangarRash here's a great example of the issue.  Until the universe ends, I'll never remember `.suffix` in swift :)  Google something like (type directly in to say safari browser) "swift ios get the tail of a large string".  The overwhelmingly most viewed answer is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32849789/how-to-get-last-4-characters-of-a-string  Note that that QA was closed (almost a decade ago!) but the answer it leads to is trash (and indeed, these days, nothing to do with the question asked). Even vadian's answer on 32849789 is (after a decade) really only "OK" (cont ..)

Comment: ( .. the completely historic crap should at best be a comment). That QA 32849789 is an example of where (a) Stackoverflow should just utterly delete such generally garbage "now-historic" QA as they cause nothing but confusion (but SO is an organization that will never change such policies), or (b) fattie puts in a new three-word answer "(huge letters)2024 use .suffix(/huge letters)".  That's my take !

Answer (score 0):

### 2024 simple answer

Normally ...

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: req) { (_,_,_) in
...
...
}
task.resume()
```

Just add this

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: req) { (_,_,_) in
...
...
}

___obs = task.progress.observe(\.fractionCompleted) { prog, _ in
    print("frac ", prog.fractionCompleted)
}

task.resume()
```

That's it.

You have to keep the observation somewhere

```
var ___obs: NSKeyValueObservation?
```

Note too that if you prefer, just use a timer and simply look at `task.progress. etc` and do whatever you want with it; you don't even have to bother with an observor if you prefer just using a timer and doing it yourself.

---

### NOTE!

When you call say an api, lambda or any calculation such as cloud.com/get/stuff.pl, let's say the return is 100mb.

What happens is:

1. The server will be thinking, perhaps for some time, generating the big json result. In practice some code on the web server (usually nginx) literally asks some database or process for the big json result.
2. The 400mb of json is communicated from the server to you.

Step two takes say a couple of minutes per GB and **during that time progress measurement will work perfectly**.

However, **step 1** usually is instant - fractions of a second. **BUT often *step 1* can take some minutes.**

If you're silly (wave!) it's easy to forget that step one can be macroscopic.  **Of course, during step 1, simply nothing happens with progress management.**

(On a UX, you'd probably show "waiting for server ..." during step 1 and *then* once step 2 begins, you'd show the progress animation.)

All of this has nothing to do with iOS, the same "step 1, before step 2 even begins" issue applies in browsers, from shells, etc etc.

(Note too that nginx famously times out if "step 1" is too long - and that is literally what has happened when you see a 504.)

Take care you don't get "gotchya'd", not matter how many api apps you've built :)

Comment: Apparently, in your other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78044382/what-causes-task-progress-observe-fractioncompleted-to-behave-very-poorly-th), you discovered some idiosyncrasies of this pattern. (I was answering that when you deleted it. Lol.) Cached responses can result in that sort of behavior. Another stumbling block is if that sometimes the % completed simply cannot be calculated (streamed responses, compression, etc.), so one might observe something like `countOfBytesReceived` instead. But if you found other issues during your research, you might want to share that.

Comment: Sorry about the deletion!!  Yes I just didn't realize/spaced the lambda in question had a huge calculation time, before the actual transmission began - silly!  edited in a gotchya warning here  @Rob TY

Answer (score -1):

Add `URLSessionDownloadDelegate`, create a `URLSession` with delegate

`URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)`

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64) {

    _progress = Float(totalBytesWritten) / Float(totalBytesExpectedToWrite)
}
```

Answer (score -5):

There are three types of session tasks. This is copied from Apple's website [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession).

1. Data tasks send and receive data using NSData objects. Data tasks are intended for short, often interactive requests to a server.
2. Upload tasks are similar to data tasks, but they also send data (often in the form of a file), and support background uploads while the app isn’t running.
3. Download tasks retrieve data in the form of a file, and support background downloads and uploads while the app isn’t running.

You should use the *download* task instead of *data* task because its delegate methods will allow you to track the download progress. [Here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessiondownloaddelegate) is the link to the download delegate methods that call what you are asking for.

Comment: Isn't his question about how to get a progress indicator from URLSession?

Comment: Here's another link that can step you through it: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url_loading_system/downloading_files_from_websites

Comment: No, his question is how to get progress updates. He is currently using a data session and he should be using a download session with delegate methods (as my answer states).